# do i really need to change rotor when mileage is under 29,000 miles?

Tags: brake-rotor

The brake pad icon on my dashboard lights up and when i brought it to the shop they said i need to replace the rotor too.  my car has 29,000 mile only- is it right that i should replace the rotor this early?

Answer (score 3):

Brake wear does not always depend on mileage - for example a car used entirely in city stop-start traffic will wear out it's brakes quicker than one used entirely on highways, simply because the brakes are used a lot more per mile travelled.

It seems to be quite an emotive subject, with some people saying you should replace the discs (rotors) every time you change the pads, and others suggesting they only need doing when worn down - I tend to go more for the latter. Bear in mind that the minimum thickness is just that - a minimum - so if they are likely to wear below that before the next pad change, then they need to be done this time. The manufacturer's spec should list the minimum thickness for your car.

You also need to take into account potential other damage to the discs - if they are warped or show any signs of cracking, they need replacing immediately. This might not be obvious to your naked eye, especially with slight warping...

As Watsche says, brakes are vital and must not be skimped on, so if in doubt, get them changed...

Answer (score 1):

There exist a minimum for every kind of rotors. If this minimum is reached, you need to change your rotors, even if they look good and work well. Watch my video what could happen, if you don't change them [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8R58aN0dkk). If you are under the minimum, your rotor lost a lot of mass. They overheat more faster and produce structural damage. Breaks are the most important parts of your car, so don't try to save on them.

If you have a good rims, buy ceramic break pads. They don't burn the dust into your rims.

Answer (score 0):

Brake discs/rotors, as with the brake pads, should be regarded as consumables. If you run your thumb nail across a rotor and you feel roughness or other wise grooving, replace them. Manufacturers give a minimum thickness for any given rotor. But a minimum thickness must be across all of the rotor. To arrive at this minimum thickness you must first re-surface the rotor, and then measure for minimum thickness. The rotors do not wear evenly. They may be thinner at the centre of the braking area, and ridged at the outer part of the braking area, with corrosion at the inner area. Cheaper and safer to just replace them. New pads have to 'bed-in' into the rotor that is on the vehicle. You will get full braking on the new pads sooner, with a little longer pad life, with new rotors.